# Can bond rotation take place in Pinacol-Pinacolon rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, bond

I was given a question of pinacol pinacolon rearrangement of **butan-2,3-diol** where the methyl groups were anti to the respective hydroxy groups. Can the **C2-C3** bond be rotated to allow hydrogen to be anti to the leaving hydroxy group, but I have heard that mechanism of this rearrangement is concerted. Therefore I can't decide the major product.

Comment: Yes,it can be, as in this configuration, the antibonding sigma orbital of the leaving group will be parallel to the lone pairs of the other hydroxyl group

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand how this will lead to bond rotation. Can you explain a little more?